# Isuzu rodeo 3.2 V6 engine runing too cold?

Tags: temperature, isuzu, rodeo

I own Isuzu Rodeo 2004 3.2 V6. 
I connected an OBD device and I noticed that the engine temp is around 72~C, the gauge on the dashboard looks fine (seats on the center where is suppose to be).

- I check the thermostat and it's not stuck.
- I couldn't find anywhere the what should be engine operating temperature in this vehicle
- what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, engine operating temperature is around 90 degrees Celsius. However, there may be [several temperature sensors](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/46303/does-the-dash-temperature-sender-unit-also-provide-input-to-the-ecu), each of which can read the temperature at a different location. Most likely, the gauge is using a different temperature sensor than the ECU is using. Different locations may have different temperatures.

Several possibilities:

- The ECU temperature sensor is reading the temperature at a different point than the gauge on the dashboard and thus the temperature at the different point differs (most likely explanation as the gauge seats on the center)
- ECU temperature sensor is faulty and reports incorrect readings
- Thermostat is old and opens at a different temperature than a new thermostat opens at, but if the gauge is fine, it would require an equal and opposite error to seem fine

Comment: Thanks. I will try to replace the temp sensor. do you think the current situation could cause high fuel consumption?